# org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;) and chain reaction

Tags: java, spring, maven

I was trying to make a web application (not coded by me) to run, but, upon deployment, I am getting the following exceptions.

1. > java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V

I have already checked and validated that there are no version conflicts for the spring-blabla jars in the **WEB-INF/libs** folder (I am using spring version 3.2.0.M1) and the dependecies in the **pom.xml** file have the following form.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have been quite desperate, so, as a last resort, I checked a chinese site and experimented with the following listener in the **web.xml**file

```
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
```

under the already existing one:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

When I am running the application, I am no longer receiving the previous exception, but another one,

> Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.isDefaultJndiEnvironmentAvailable()Z

and I really have no idea what to do ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's very likely your runtime is reading Spring 2.0 instead of 3.2. Take a look at Spring 2 [ConfigurableWebApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.html), it doesn't have `setId(String)` method.

I would start debugging the problem by checking the jar/war file, see if any duplicate version of Spring. Also check the web container classpath (eg: tomcat lib folder). If there's a Spring 2 jars in there it could cause confusion

Comment: you were right, there was an evil 3.1 context forgotten in the web container classpath! thanks a lot :)